# Get value of checked radio button in radio button list

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i can get value of checked radio button in radio button list.Here is my code

```
   <div class="report_type">
      <input type='radio' name='choices' value='balance'>Balance Report <br/>
      <input type='radio' name='choices' value='invoice'>Invoice Report <br/>
      <input type='radio' name='choices' value='payment'>Payment Report <br/>
      <input type='radio' name='choices' value='traffic'>Traffic Report <br/>
      <input type='radio' name='choices' value='cdr'>CDRs
    </div>
```

Give any help????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get value any checked  radio button by using following code

```
var val = $("input:radio[name='choices']:checked").val();
alert(val);  //give value of checked radio button
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.report_type input').click(function() {
   alert($(this).val())
})
```

Comment: `change` is better then `click` as `click` triggered only by mouse clicks... And use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()` knowing the DOM properties saves you from redundant jQuery code.

Comment: @gdoron - If you focus a radio button (e.g. tab to one) and then press the space bar to select it, the `click` event is still fired. So in this case, `click` and `change` are pretty much the same. Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/xKqRu/

Comment: @JamesAllardice. Correct. My bad. **+1** though it was't what he was asking about...

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select the set of radio buttons, and the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector to select the one that is selected. You can then use the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to get the value of that element:

```
$("input[name='choices']:checked").val();
```

Alternatively, you could just select all `input` elements that are descendants of the `div`:

```
$("div.report_type input:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

http://api.jquery.com/val/

see the last example

Answer (score 0):

Short & clear on ES-2015, no dependencies:

```js
function getValueFromRadioButton( name ){
  return [...document.getElementsByName(name)]
         .reduce( (rez, btn) => (btn.checked ? btn.value : rez), null)
}

console.log( getValueFromRadioButton('payment') );
```

```html
<div>  
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="offline">
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="online">
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="part" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="payment" value="free">
</div>
```